# How to pass strings from arrays to pointers while also using structures (in c)

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, structure

The point of this code is to read a string from the user (which is less than 50 characters) and then use the letters function to put the letters of the string in a pointer in such a way that each letter is going only once and then also counting the occurrence of each letter. Finally, with the use of report function it should output in the screen everything I just explained. For example,
the user enters "Hello" the program outputs:

```
H : 1    
e : 1    
l : 2   
o : 1
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct charact {
    char ch;
    int occurs;
    struct charact *next;
};

typedef struct charact Char;
typedef Char * ListofChar;
typedef Char * CharNode_ptr;
void letters(char name[50], ListofChar * chars_ptr);
void report(ListofChar chars);
Char * createnode(char ch);

int main() {
    char name[50];
    ListofChar chars = NULL;
    scanf("%s", name);
    letters(name, &chars);
    report(chars);
    return 0;
}

Char * createnode(char ch) {
    CharNode_ptr newnode_ptr ;
    newnode_ptr = malloc(sizeof (Char));
    newnode_ptr -> ch = ch;
    newnode_ptr -> occurs = 0;
    newnode_ptr -> next = NULL;
    return newnode_ptr;
}

void letters(char name[50], ListofChar * lst_ptr) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; name[i]!='\0'; i++){
        //everything is done here
    }
    return;
}

void report(ListofChar chars) {
    int i;
    // this is only to output the results
    return;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I don't know how to solve the problem, I only have a basic understanding of pointers but because the finals are just around the corner the teachers decided it was a time for a huge difficulty spike. So here I am trying to understand what I should do and why.

Comment: Never hide pointers behind typedefs, it does nothing except making the code much harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding you want to use single linked list for connecting the nodes together. In the sample program i added new nodes at he beginning. head pointer holds the address of last added node.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct charact {
 char ch;
 int occurs;
 struct charact *next;
};

typedef struct charact Char;
typedef Char * ListofChar;
typedef Char * CharNode_ptr;
void letters(char name[50], ListofChar * chars_ptr);
void report(ListofChar chars);
Char * createnode(char ch, ListofChar * head_ptr);

int main() {
 char name[50];
 ListofChar chars = NULL;
 scanf("%s", name);
 letters(name, &chars);
 report(chars);
 return 0;
}

Char * createnode(char ch,ListofChar * head_ptr ) {
  CharNode_ptr newnode_ptr;
  ListofChar  temp;
  temp = *head_ptr;
  while(temp) {
     if( temp->ch  == ch) {
     temp->occurs += 1;
     return;
     }
     temp= temp->next;
 }
 newnode_ptr = malloc(sizeof (Char));
 newnode_ptr -> ch = ch;
 newnode_ptr -> occurs = 1;
 newnode_ptr -> next = *head_ptr;
  *head_ptr = newnode_ptr;
  return newnode_ptr;
 }

void letters(char name[50], ListofChar * lst_ptr) {
  int i;
  for(i=0; name[i]!='\0'; i++){
     createnode(name[i],lst_ptr);
     //everything is done here
   }
 return;
  }

 void report(ListofChar chars) {
    int i;
    while(chars)
     {
   printf("%c %d \n",chars->ch,chars->occurs);
   chars = chars->next;
    }
   //printf("%c \n",chars->ch);
   // this is only to output the results
   return;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, your code works fine. Just a question, why does it show the letters in reverse? For example it won't show h:1 e:1 l:2 o:1 but start from then o move to the l and so on.

Comment: Thaks for the reply. I have added new node at the beginning,  ie name[0] is the last node and name[strlen(name) -1] is the first node.
if you want to print in same order, you can either modify the for loop as 

        for(i=0; name[i]!='\0'; i++);
            while(i--)                 
                             createnode(name[i],lst_ptr);

or in report function you can start printing the nodes from last node to first node.